# How to pass a string parameter on bash function?

Tags: bash, string, function, parameter

I have this code that does work:

```
get_parameter ()
{
   echo "$query" | sed -n 's/^.*name=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"
}
```

But I want to replace the "name" with the parameter that I pass to get_parameter

```
get_parameter ()
{
   echo "$query" | sed -n 's/^.*$1=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"
}
NAME=$( get_parameter name )
```

This however, doesn't work. Where am I wrong?

Comment: As an aside, it only needs a single sed call... `sed -rn "/^.*$1=([^&]*).*$/{ s//\1/; s/%20/_/g; p }"` ...(I used an underscore to stop it line wrapping)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use variables in the LHS and RHS of a sed substitution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69112/how-can-i-use-variables-in-the-lhs-and-rhs-of-a-sed-substitution)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Quoting](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html): In short, variables are not replaced with their values inside `'single-quoted'` strings (aka. "variable substitution"). You need to use any one of `"double quotes"`, `$'dollar quotes'`, or

```
<<EOF
here strings
EOF
```

Answer (score 5):

As [l0b0 pointed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21167/how-to-pass-a-string-parameter-on-bash-function/21174#21174), you can't use single quotes here. Apart from that, in your example you don't have to use `sed` either. It looks far cleaner with `grep`:

```
get_parameter ()
{
   echo "$query" | grep -o "${1}=[^&]*" | sed "s/%20/ /g"
}
```

Without `echo`:

```
get_parameter ()
{
   <<< "$query" grep -o "${1}=[^&]*" | sed "s/%20/ /g"
}
```

And finally, without the second `sed` (just `bash`):

```
get_parameter ()
{
   <<< "${query//%20/ }" grep -o "${1}=[^&]*"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
echo "$query" | sed -n 's/^.*$1=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"
```

to:

```
echo "$query" | sed -n 's/^.*'"$1"'=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concating it with rest command by replace `name` with `'$1'` like the following:

```bsh
sed -n 's/^.*'$1'=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"
```

Comment: Note that you are leaving `$1` unquoted in the shell.

Comment: @they

I know and that is the right way to write it!!
Also, I am already using it with the same syntax, so you might misunderstand it!!

Comment: To quote the expansion of `$1` in your command, use `sed -n 's/^.*'"$1"'=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"`.  Test your command with `$1` set to the string `1 2 3`. Then also test with `*` and `/` and add a caveat to you answer about how `$1` would be interpreted as a regular expression, and that it can't contain the delimiter used with the substitution command, and what to do instead.