# How can I use variables in the LHS and RHS of a sed substitution?

Tags: sed

I want to do:

```
cat update_via_sed.sh | sed 's/old_name/new_name/' > new_update_via_sed.sh
```

in my program.

But I want to use variables, e.g.

```
old_run='old_name_952'
new_run='old_name_953'
```

I have tried using them but the substitution doesn't happen (no error).
I have tried:

```
cat update_via_sed.sh | sed 's/old_run/new_run/'
cat update_via_sed.sh | sed 's/$old_run/$new_run/'
cat update_via_sed.sh | sed 's/${old_run}/${new_run}/'
```

Comment: You can find the answer in [Use a parameter in a command argument](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67200/use-a-parameter-in-a-command-argument).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

'in-place' sed (usng the -i flag) was the answer.  Thanks to peterph.

```
sed -i "s@$old@$new@" file
```

Comment: You have the quotes in the wrong place. quotes must be around variables, not `s@` (which is not special to the shell in any way). Best is to put everything inside quotes like `sed -i "s@$old@$new@" file`. Note that `-i` is not a standard `sed` option.

Comment: how can I escape `$` in this command. Like, I am going to change `$xxx` as a whole to the value of a variable `$JAVA_HOME`. I tried `sed -i "s@\$xxx@$JAVA_HOME@" file`, but error says `no previous regular expression`

Answer (score 54):

You could do:

```
sed "s/$old_run/$new_run/" < infile > outfile
```

But beware that `$old_run` would be taken as a regular expression and so any special characters that the variable contains, such as `/` or `.` would have to [be escaped](/a/129063). Similarly, in `$new_run`, the `&` and `\` characters would need to be treated specially and you would have to escape the `/` and newline characters in it.

If the content of `$old_run` or `$new_run` is not under your control, then it's **critical** to perform that escaping, or otherwise [that code amounts to a code injection vulnerability](/a/297128).

Comment: I was using single quote in sed params, switched to double quotes and it worked file. Awesome.

Comment: it isn't that `sed` alone will not use regex but `sed -E` would ?

Comment: @Kiwy, no. `-e` is to specify a `sed` _**e**xpression_, so you can pass more than one (as in `sed -e exp1 -e exp2`) or combinations of files and expressions (`sed -f file -e exp`). You may be confusing with `-E` which with some implementations, tells sed to use EREs instead of BREs.

Comment: I mistyped, but OK, that explain why i have so many issues using sed without `-E` I only master the extended regex not the regular one. Thanks for the explanaiton.

Comment: @Kiwy, see also [the linked Q&A](/a/129063) for more options supported by some `sed` implementations for yet more regular expression syntaxes.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thank for the links, I try to use EREs most of the time. I can't stand the synthax of BREs

Comment: Can you look at this please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56459572/replace-a-string-in-a-file-with-contents-copied-from-another-file

Comment: i used sed 's/something-with-variable/'something-with"$varaible"-something-else''... meaning, if i used single quote for the sed, then the replacement string i had to use single quote and inside use double quote

Answer (score 33):

This worked:

```
cat update_via_sed.sh | sed 's/'"$old_run"'/'"$new_run"'/'
```

As I want to 'reuse' the same file I actually use this for anyone wishing a similar approach:

```
cat update_via_sed.sh | sed 's/'"$old_run"'/'"$new_run"'/' > new_update; mv -f new_update update_via_sed.sh
```

The above created a new file then deletes the current file than rename the new file to be the current file.

Comment: You don't need cat, mv, or extra '' unless you're going to have special characters in them. So it's `sed -i s/"$old"/"$new"/ update_via_sed.sh`. However be aware that this does not work for any value of old and new. e.g. it must not contain / etc., as $old is still a search and $new a replacement pattern where some characters have special meanings.

Comment: `sed -i "s/$old/$new/"` is ok too (with the above precautions). `sed` usually considers the separator to be the first character after the `s` command - i.e. if your variables contain slashes `/` but not lets say at (`@`), you can use "s@$old@$new@".

Answer (score 23):

You can use variables in sed as long as it's in a double quote (not a single quote):

```
sed "s/$var/r_str/g" file_name >new_file
```

If you have a forward slash (`/`) in the variable then use different separator like below

```
sed "s|$var|r_str|g" file_name >new_file
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning needing to use double quotes. That was my problem.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, including the use of `|` as in my case, the variables contains a path so it has `/` in it

Comment: For some reasons the pipe `|` worked for me on MacOS 10.14, but other seperators like `@` or `#` not. I had forward slashes in my env var too.

Answer (score 3):

`man bash` gives this about single quoting

> Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves  the  literal
>          value  of  each  character within the quotes.  A single quote
>          may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by  a
>          backslash.

Whatever you type on the command line, bash interprets it and then it sends the result to the program it is supposed to be sent to.In this case, if you use `sed 's/$old_run/$new_run/'`, bash first sees the `sed`, it recognises it as an executable present in `$PATH` variable. The `sed` executable requires an input. Bash looks for the input and finds `'s/$old_run/$new_run/'`. Single quotes say bash not to interpret the content in them and pass them as they are. So, bash then passes them to sed. Sed gives an error because `$` can occur only at the end of line.

Instead if we use double quotes, i.e., `"s/$old_run/$new_run/"`, then bash sees this and interprets `$old_run` as a variable name and makes a substitution (this phase is called variable expansion). This is indeed what we required.

But, you have to be careful using double quotes because, they are interpreted first by bash and then given to sed. So, some symbols like ` must be escaped before using them.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo $d1 | sed -i 's/zkserver1/'${d1}'/g' deva_file
sed: -e expression #1, char 26: unterminated `s' command
```

In `$d1` I am storing values

I cannot replace the value from the variable, so I tried the following command it is working:

```
echo $d1 | sed -i 's/zkserver1/'"${d1}"'/g' deva_file
```

missing double quotation mark in `"${d1}"`, that was the error.

Answer (score 1):

At risk of being flippant - have you considered `perl`.

Which - amongst other things - is quite good at doing 'sed style' operations, but also a more fully featured programming thingummy.

It *looks* like in your example, what you're *actually* trying to do is increment a number.

So how about:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all'; 

while ( <DATA> ) {
    s/old_name_(\d+)/"old_name_".($1+1)/e;
    print;
}

__DATA__
old_name_932
```

or as a one liner - sed style:

```
perl -pe 's/old_name_(\d+)/"old_name_".($1+1)/e'
```

Answer (score -3):

break the string

bad => linux see a string $old_run :

```
sed 's/$old_run/$new_run/'
```

good => linux see a variable $old_run:

```
sed 's/'$old_run'/'$new_run'/'
```

Comment: And if `$old_run` or `$new_run` contains spaces?

Answer (score -4):

You can also use Perl:

```
perl -pi -e ""s/$val1/$val2/g"" file
```

Comment: Consider variables that may have spaces in their values.  The empty strings around the Perl expression (`""`) won't do anything.