# How to change special character in linux using variable

Tags: linux, sed

I am using this `sed` command in particular file, but it doesn't work.

e.g.

```
a="adsfkndsa%/{}==admfkdsa"  
b=sadkfjdsaklfj  

sed -i -e 's/$a/$b/g' /tmp/sample.txt
```

Please suggest another way.

Comment: Are you actually using this quoting: `sed -i -e 's/$a/$b/g"`, open with single quote and close with double quotes?

Comment: Ya i am try both sed -i -e 's/$a/$b/g'  & sed -i -e "s/$a/$b/g" but it is not working

Comment: Could you post an small part of the file that you want to modify? A part that include the string that you want to change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use variables when doing a sed?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69112/how-can-i-use-variables-when-doing-a-sed)

Comment: The question was clear enough, and a duplicate - but not that one.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried this, and it works on my system (Debian 8):

```
sed -i.bak "s|$a|$b|g" /tmp/sample.txt
```

You need to change the delimiter, since the variable `$a` contains a `/`.

Before:

```
cat /tmp/sample.txt.bak 
foo
adsfkndsa%/{}==admfkdsa
bar
```

After:

```
cat /tmp/sample.txt
foo
sadkfjdsaklfj
bar
```

Edit, sed version info:

```
sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
```