# sed replace with variable

Tags: centos, sed, string

I am trying to replace matching string with other string. This is what I have

```
ZKHOSTS="host1,host2,host3"
old_string="tsd.storage.hbase.zk_quorum*"
new_string="tsd.storage.hbase.zk_quorum = $ZKHOSTS"

sed -i '/$old_string/c\$new_string' /etc/opentsdb/opentsdb.conf
```

which isn't working as excepted.

I even tried following

```
sed -i 's/$old_string/$new_string/g' /etc/opentsdb/opentsdb.conf

sed -i '/${old_string}/${new_string}/g' /etc/opentsdb/opentsdb.conf
```

I dont know what wrong I am doing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use double quotes, like:

```
sed -i "s/$old_string/$new_string/g" /etc/opentsdb/opentsdb.conf
```

Comment: But beware of the [limitations and potential security implications of that approach](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/69136/22565)