# Problem with passing a variable to sed

Tags: shell, sed, quoting

I know that when passing a variable to sed, one should use double quote. So when I was using sed to display a line of a file given a line number:

```
sed '894!d' cloud.cpp
```

It works, but since I also want to pass the line number 894 to sed as a variable, so I tried:

```
lnum=894
sed "$lnum!d" cloud.cpp
```

But it does not work, and even single quote with same syntax does not work:

```
sed "894!d" cloud.cpp
```

So in this case how can I still pass a variable to sed.

Comment: This is purely a shell question, so you should specify which shell you are using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you mentioned, you must use double quotes because when you use single quotes for strings, its contents will be treated literally.
But in your case, you have a combination of patern and variable. So you should use single quotes for the pattern, and double quotes for the variable:

```
sed "$lnum"'!d' cloud.cpp
```

Comment: That won't work in `(t)csh` shells and didn't tell the real problem under the hood.

Answer (score 9):

If your variable contains only digit, what you have done is correct:

```
sed "$lnum!d" cloud.cpp
```

For passing shell variable to `sed` in general, please read [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/69136/38906).

---

Now, you have done it correctly in this case, but it still doesn't work. It dues to your shell, which probably `bash`, `zsh` or `csh`. Those shells support history expansion, which is denoted by `!` (This feature is original from `csh` and copied later by `bash` and `zsh`).

In `bash`, `zsh`, history expansion is enabled by default in interactive session, and will be performed inside double quotes.

In `zsh`:

```
$ seq 10 | sed "10!d" # <-- press enter
$ seq 10 | sed "10dash"
```

as `dash` is my latest command in history start with `d`.

In `bash`:

```
$ seq 10 | sed "10!d"
bash: !d": event not found
```

as I don't have any command in bash history start with `d`.

You can turn off history expansion:

```
set +H
```

or:

```
set +o histexpand
```

in `bash` and:

```
set -K
```

or:

```
setopt nohistexpand
```

in `zsh`.

---

For more portable way, without relying on your shell options, you can always do:

```
sed "$lnum"\!d cloud.cpp
```

which causes your shell treating `!` literally.

Comment: `sed "$lnum\!d" cloud.cpp` doesn't work because bash won't discard the blackslash. Try it.

Comment: @Cyker: Yes right, my copy-paste issue, fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't mention which shell you are using. The answer below assumes it's `bash`.

---

You are triggering history expansion in the shell. From `man bash`:

> #### `!string`
>
> Refer to the most recent command preceding the current position in the history list starting with string.

The weird thing about it is that:

> If enabled, history expansion will be performed unless an `!` appearing in double quotes is escaped using a backslash. The backslash preceding the `!`  is not removed.

Therefore I think quoting them separately is probably the best solution:

```sh
sed "$lnum"'!d' cloud.cpp
```

This also works (saving you a char):

```sh
sed "$lnum"\!d cloud.cpp
```

This also works (if you favor double quotes):

```sh
sed "$lnum""!""d" cloud.cpp
```

Comment: Note that anything other than the second one won't work in `(t)csh`

Comment: @cuonglm I already mentioned the answer is for `bash`. It should apply to bash-compliant shells as well. Obviously `csh` is not one of them.