# Json. How to add a sentence after :

Tags: text-processing, sed, scripting, json

The following is an extroct from a json file, that I have:

```
 },
   {
    "name": "asdasd",
    "script": "dsad.js",
    "merge_logs": ture,
    "error_file": "/ofghfghgfh.log",
    "out_file": "/fghgfhfgg",
    "cwd": "",
    "autorestart": true,
    "log_date_format"  : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z",
    "env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "desa",
    "KEY": "VtZOiz0Qc4afFs6j+h2r"
    }
  }]
```

I want to add a phrase after "KEY": substituting the value that it has now.

I tried "sed" but I added it to the end of the line

```
 sed '/KEY/s/$/1234/g' .json
```

I would need to use the "-i" option to change the file directly.

Comment: Use json tools, not sed.

Comment: It is not clear what he expected output is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this (use `i` option to modify the file but first check if it is working properly or not):

```
sed -E 's/("KEY":) (".*")/\1 anything/g' .json
```

It will break line in two parts first will match `"KEY":` and then space and it will replace second part with anything.

Let us say `KEY='"1234"'` (by using single quote KEY's value will be `"1234"`). Then you can use.

```
sed -E "s/(\"KEY\":) (\".*\")/\1 $KEY/g" .json
```

Comment: how would it be if I wanted to put a variable on the "sed" for example: `KEY="1234"                      sed -E 's/("KEY":) (".*")/\1 $KEY/g' .json` I have tried this but it does not work

Comment: @ortiga you need to use double quotes instead of single. See this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/69112/255251

Comment: `sed -Ei "s/("KEY":) (".*")/\1 $KEY/g" .json` no work :(

Comment: @ortiga see my updated answer.

Comment: quit `(".*")` and work

Answer (score 7):

`sed` is the wrong tool for this job.  One of the right tools is `jq`.

```
% cat wibble.json                               
[
  {
    "name": "asdasd",
    "script": "dsad.js"
  },
  {
    "log_date_format"  : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z",
    "env": {
            "NODE_ENV": "desa",
            "KEY": "VtZOiz0Qc4afFs6j+h2r"
    }
  }
]
% jq  '.[1]."env"."KEY" = "1234"' wibble.json
[
  {
    "name": "asdasd",
    "script": "dsad.js"
  },
  {
    "log_date_format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z",
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "desa",
      "KEY": "1234"
    }
  }
]
%
```

It even spots that your JSON is not actually valid.

```
% jq . ortiga.json
parse error: Invalid literal at line 4, column 23
%
```

Answer (score 0):

nested structures (like xml, html, json, etc) must be processed by utilities which are aware of the data model. if relied upon the line-aware tools like `sed`, `awk` then there always will be a chance for false positives.

hence JSON inputs must be processed by JSON aware tools. jq answer has been already given, here's an alternative solution based on *[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc)*:

```
bash $ cat file.json | jtc -w'<KEY>l' -eu echo '"1234"' \;
{
   "autorestart": true,
   "cwd": "",
   "env": {
      "KEY": "1234",
      "NODE_ENV": "desa"
   },
   "error_file": "/ofghfghgfh.log",
   "log_date_format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z",
   "merge_logs": true,
   "name": "asdasd",
   "out_file": "/fghgfhfgg",
   "script": "dsad.js"
}
bash $
```