# How to use variable in sed command

Tags: shell-script, sed, command-line, variable

I am trying to delete two lines ( 7 and 8) from a `.txt` file. For this I am using following code:-

```
#!/bin/sh
Column="7"
sed '"$Column",8d' myfile.txt > result.txt
```

on running this script, I am getting this error:-

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `"'
```

Please tell me how to use variable as a part of sed command.

Comment: Using double quotes within single quotes doesn't help, you'll have to keep the double quotes outside the single quotes.

Comment: See [How can I use variables in the LHS and RHS of a sed substitution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69112/how-can-i-use-variables-in-the-lhs-and-rhs-of-a-sed-substitution)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables are not expanded in single quotes. Use this:

```
sed "${Column},8d" myfile.txt > result.txt
```