# How to use sed to replace variable value with a variable of the same name?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I'm trying to write a script that updates a server config file to the latest format. The purpose of the script is to copy over existing (defined) variables to the latest config (in a temp file), then copy/overwrite the old config file with the newly generated one.

From my understanding, using [double quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/69136/353848) will expand variables in `sed`. This seems to work fine when only one variable is used in the pattern:

```
sed -i "s|random|$PASSWORD|g" /tmp/latest_config
```

In the above example, the temp config file is successfully modified, and all instances of `random` are replaced with the value of `$PASSWORD`. However, this doesn't work the other way:

```
sed -i "s|$PASSWORD|random|g" /tmp/latest_config
```

In the above example, nothing happens, and no sed errors etc. The value of `$PASSWORD` in the temp config file is not modified...

NOTE: `$PASSWORD` in the first example is being sourced from "old" config file at the top of this script, but the goal of the second example would be replacing variable value...

---

I've seen dozens of similar "variable" questions on the SE network, however many of the answers are wrong (e.g. using single quotes, etc) or simply do not work for me. I have tried many formats, including single and double  quotation marks, brackets (to differentiate environment variable from the variable being actually searched for by `sed`)... nothing has worked so far, e.g.:

```
sed -i "s|$PASSWORD|$PASSWORD|g" /tmp/latest_config
sed -i "s|$PASSWORD|${PASSWORD}|g" /tmp/latest_config
sed -i "s|\$PASSWORD|${PASSWORD}|g" /tmp/latest_config
sed -i 's|$PASSWORD|"${PASSWORD}"|g' /tmp/latest_config
sed -i 's|\$PASSWORD|"${PASSWORD}"|g' /tmp/latest_config
```

The only solution that works is a sort of [hacky workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32739762/1718491):

```
sed -i "s|\(^PASSWORD=\).*|PASSWORD=\"$PASSWORD\"|g" /tmp/latest-config
```

Why? Do I need to export the existing variables first, or is this as good as it gets?...

Comment: The problem is likely that the shell expands $PASSWORD to whatever the password is, and then sed parses the resulting value as if it were a regex when in fact you want a literal string comparison. So sed's behaviour is going to depend on the contents of $PASSWORD and any non alpha numeric characters it contains. I recommend you use a template source file rather than trying to modify in place.

Comment: @Colin thanks for your suggestion. By chance, do you have a link or example of how I could proceed with a template source file (intermediate file?). Thanks!

Comment: It's a fairly common way of automating configuration. And it's typically done this way for exactly the reasons you've described: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841195/how-can-i-script-file-generation-from-a-template-using-bash . Depending on how many servers you have to automate it may be worth putting the variables you're using in the config, into a database.

Comment: @Colin thanks for all this, I wish I could upvote your comments!