# Replace with lines number in specific line of a text file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, wc

What I need to do (in Bash) is a replacement of a specific characted of the second line in a text file with the number of lines in this file. So, this does the job of counting the lines:

```
cat test.csv | wc -l
```

The following command does the job of changing the `;0;` encountered in the file to be modified with the number I got from the above command (in this case `33`)

```
sed -i '2s/;0;/;33;/' test.csv
```

But now I am trying to join the two above so that they work as a single command (I need it in my application). I've tried in many ways shown below, but with no success.

```
sed '2s/;0;/`cat test.csv | wc -l`/' test.csv
cat test.csv | wc -l | sed '2s/;0;//' test.csv
sed '2s/;0;/`${cat test.csv | wc -l}`/' test.csv
sed -e '2s/;0;/echo `${cat test.csv | wc -l}`/;e' test.csv
sed -e '2s/;0;/${echo `cat test.csv | wc -l`}/' test.csv
$rn=`cat test.csv | wc -l`; sed '2s/;0;/${rn}/' test.csv
```

Could anyone help me solve this out?

Comment: Add sample text and the expected output to your question.

Comment: use `$( )` (parenthesis) for command expansion, not `${ }`(accolade) that do variable expansion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all of your commands, you use single quotes around the `sed` expression.  The shell will not do expansions inside single quotes.

Instead (temporarily breaking out of the single quoted expression for a double quoted command substitution),

```
sed '2s/;0;/;'"$( wc -l <test.csv )"';/' test.csv
```

or (using double quotes for the whole expression),

```
sed "2s/;0;/;$( wc -l <test.csv );/" test.csv
```

or (using a variable, and then double quotes as above),

```
lines=$( wc -l <test.csv ); sed "2s/;0;/;$lines;/" test.csv
```

(don't use `-i` until you know it works!)

Related:

- [Have backticks (i.e. `cmd`) in *sh shells been deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927)
- [How can I use variables in the LHS and RHS of a sed substitution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69112)

Comment: Thanks! That worked. :-)