# Printing all lines between two strings, with one as a user input, using sed

Tags: sed, quoting, user-input

I'm trying to use:

```
sed -n '/String1/,/String2/p' Filename
```

to print all lines between String1 and String2. Although I want to add String1 as a user input so,

```
read $userinput
sed -n '/$userinput/,/String2/p' Filename.
```

But as the input is within quotation is is read as the string `$userinput` instead of the given input.

Comment: Closely related: [How can I use variables in the LHS and RHS of a sed substitution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69112/how-can-i-use-variables-in-the-lhs-and-rhs-of-a-sed-substitution)

Answer (score 0):

Simply like this:

```
read userinput                         # without sigil '$'
sed -n "/$userinput/,/String2/p" file  # with double quotes
```

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words