# Bash Script: Add/Remove comment on the matching lines

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, sed

I have a file `~/.zshrc` with the following lines

```
...
#export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.0/bin:$PATH"
#export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.0/sbin:$PATH"
##export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/bin:$PATH"
##export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/sbin:$PATH"
#export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin:$PATH"
#export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/sbin:$PATH"
#export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin:$PATH"
#export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/sbin:$PATH"
...
```

I am preparing a small bash script, which accepts the PHP version (first arg) and action (second arg). For example dummy command may look like:

```
mycommand 7.4 comment
```

Which will only comment out the following lines form the file as

```
#export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin:$PATH"
#export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/sbin:$PATH"
```

And if you run

```
mycommand 7.1 uncomment
```

Will update only the following lines as

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/sbin:$PATH"
```

So my question is how to use `sed` or any other command in .sh script which will parse the file.
My bash script looks like below (not working)

```
# File mycommand.sh
# ...
if [[ ! -z "$1" && ! -z "$2" && "$2" = "comment" ]]; then
    # remove multi # comments if there's any
    sed -i '' 's/#*export PATH="\/usr\/local\/opt\/php@$1/export PATH="\/usr\/local\/opt\/php@$1/g'   
    # Finally add a single # comment
    sed -i '' 's/*export PATH="\/usr\/local\/opt\/php@$1/#export PATH="\/usr\/local\/opt\/php@$1/g'    
fi
if [[ ! -z "$1" && ! -z "$2" && "$2" = "uncomment" ]]; then
    # remove one or more # comments
    sed -i '' 's/#*export PATH="\/usr\/local\/opt\/php@$1/export PATH="\/usr\/local\/opt\/php@$1/g'   
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work robustly, efficiently, and portably:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

infile=~/.zshrc
tmp=$(mktemp) || exit 1

awk -v ver="$1" -v cmd="$2" '
    index($0,"php@"ver"/") {
        if      ( cmd == "comment" )   { sub(/^#*/,"#") }
        else if ( cmd == "uncomment" ) { sub(/^#+/,"")  }
        else { printf "bad cmd: %s\n", cmd | "cat>&2" }
    }
    { print }
' "$infile" > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" "$infile"
```

Change `"php@"ver"/"` to `"export PATH=\"/usr/local/opt/php@"ver"/"` if needed to avoid false matches with other lines that exist in your real input but you didn't show in your example.

If you have GNU awk you could use `-i inplace` instead of manually creating a tmp file.

Answer (score 1):

The script that you use should be changed as follows:

```
if [[ ! -z "$1" && ! -z "$2" && "$2" = "comment" ]]; then
    # remove multi # comments if there's any
    sed -i "s/#*export PATH=\"\/usr\/local\/opt\/php@$1/export PATH=\"\/usr\/local\/opt\/php@$1/g" ~/.zshrc
    # Finally add a single # comment
    sed -i "s/export PATH=\"\/usr\/local\/opt\/php@$1/#export PATH=\"\/usr\/local\/opt\/php@$1/g" ~/.zshrc
fi
if [[ ! -z "$1" && ! -z "$2" && "$2" = "uncomment" ]]; then
    # remove one or more # comments
   sed -i "s/#*export PATH=\"\/usr\/local\/opt\/php@$1/export PATH=\"\/usr\/local\/opt\/php@$1/g" ~/.zshrc
fi
```

The problems were:

1. The empty single quotes (`''`) after `sed -i`.
2. You hadn't specified the `sed` input file (`~/.zshrc`).
3. You needed to use double quotes (`"`) instead of single ones (`'`) for the shell to expand the `$1` variable first. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69112/how-can-i-use-variables-in-the-lhs-and-rhs-of-a-sed-substitution) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76808/how-do-i-use-variables-in-a-sed-command) relevant questions.

Comment: 1) If you use a delimiter char other than `/`, e.g. `:`, then you won't have to escape every `/` in the regexp or replacement text. 2) There's no need to test for `! -z "$2"` when you're explicitly testing for `"$2" = "[un]comment"`. 3) You're using `$1` in an unanchored regexp context so `1.2` will match the `142` in `...php@142yeehaw`.