# sed: -e expression#1 char 48: unterminated `s' command

Tags: linux, bash, sed

In my project in `.sh` file I wrote this command:

```
var1=`sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/\\n/g;s/^/"/g;s/$/"/g' ${var}`
sed -i "s/%PQR%/$var1/g" file2
```

Here `var` is the variable which stores location of the file that I want to update. I want double quotes to be added at the start and end of file. Also I want all the new lines to be replaced with `\n`.
example:

```
To err is to human.
This is life.
```

output:

```
"To err is to human.\nThis is life."
```

Then I want `%PQR%` in `file2` to be replaced with `var1`.

But on running pipeline, the get the error on the second command as described in the title:

```
sed: -e expression#1 char 48: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: Does it work if you use \" instead of " and also quote the var, like this: "$var" ?

I guess you could try each sed expression individually, to see if they all work.

Comment: Welcome, check at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33301370/6005145) about the use of backticks.

Comment: You've got only one backtick on that first line. Copy typo? (Please fix it.) What happens if you run the two commands separately - which one generates the error message? What's the value of `$var1` after setting it? Prefix the second `sed` command with `echo`. Does what you see look like a valid `sed` command?

Comment: That is a typing error: I have used backtick properly in my code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use variables in the LHS and RHS of a sed substitution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69112/how-can-i-use-variables-in-the-lhs-and-rhs-of-a-sed-substitution) (in particular [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/317668/377345))

Comment: I tried executing both the commands separately. Command one runs fine. There seems to be an issue with command  two. Can anyone please help with that.

Comment: "unterminated 's' command" usually means you're missing the one of the separators (the slashes), or you have a newline in the sed code that would prematurely terminate the command.

Comment: But we can't know what the issue with `sed` is, since there's an unterminated command substitution there, so even those shell commands won't run won't run. You might want to use e.g. shellcheck.net to check the syntax. Then, you show one error message, but don't tell which sed command gives it. Reduce the problem by removing the parts that are not a problem, and then show a complete, working, but _minimal_ piece of code that shows the problem, along with any values you use. Or even enable `set -x` and show the output too, so we can see what actually runs.

Comment: "_I tried executing both the commands separately. Command one runs fine. There seems to be an issue with command two._" Please [put this into your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/671915/edit). Comments are not for adding information as it's too easy to miss something.

Answer (score 1):

To encode the contents of a file as one json string, use

```
json=$(jq --slurp -R < "$file")
```

Or:

```
json=$(jq --slurp -R 'rtrimstr("\n")' < "$file")
```

To trim the newline character that delimits the last line.

And to replace some placeholder with arbitrary data, it's much easier with `perl` (the `-i` option that some `sed` implementations support was actually inspired by `perl`).

```
PLACEHOLDER='%PQR%' REPLACEMENT="$json" perl -pi -e '
  s/\Q$ENV{PLACEHOLDER}\E/$ENV{REPLACEMENT}/g' -- "$other_file"
```

It's possible with `sed`, though [you'd need to escape some characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/129059).